How can I recover books accidentally deleted on an iPad Air 5?
I accidentally deleted the iPad Books app and everything in it was deleted. Is there a way I can restore it?

The app can be downloaded from the App Store. If the books are in iCloud, they will be restored

If we assume you were logged in to your AppleID when you deleted Apple Books then the books aren't gone, they are still in Apple's cloud storage.
Download the Apple Books app from the App Store and open the app. As long as you are still logged in to your Apple ID the books will be available in Apple Books. It may take a minute or two for the entire list to be downloaded but they will reappear.
